# What layout should i use for this android UI

Tags: android-layout, android-scrollview

i want to make something like this in android

```
-----------------------------
|                            |
|                            |
|        arrow up here       |
|----------------------------|
|                            |
|     scroll-able with       |
|     components             |
|----------------------------|
|        arrow down here     |
|                            |
|                            |
-----------------------------
```

the scroll-able in the middle is't possible to use a ScrollView?
the arrow up should scroll up the scroll-able in the middle(if the layout for this is really scroll view)
and the same in the arrow down but downwards

the background should be fix and the middle scroll should only scroll the components is't possible?
what layout should i use?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your layout if you really want to use a scrollview (and not a ListView).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="up"
        android:text="UP" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- ADD YOUR COMPONENTS HERE -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="down"
        android:text="DOWN" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how to manage "up" and "down" events in your activity. Add these methods:

```
public void up(View v) {
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    scrollView.scrollBy(0, +20);
}

public void down(View v) {
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    scrollView.scrollBy(0, -20);
}
```

In this example I'm just scrolling of 20 pixels. Adjust these values to obtain what you want (for example scroll in the middle of the scrollview, or scroll by the half of the visible scrollview height).

Comment: just want to ask does the background of the parent doesn't affect the scroll view or i need to make the background of the scrollview transparent?

Comment: the default background is transparent, so if you alter parent's color, it will also affect the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Deppends what you need in the middle. You can have a `<ScrollView>` and build your xml inside your scrollview. Or you can do as suggested and use the listView. Without more information it's harder to guide you further.

Comment: Can show me how do i add another xml file inside that ScrollView?